# Why do I see a "SIGHUP or SIGTERMa:" error while trying to pass my password to sudo using echo and "|"?

Tags: sudo

### Edit: `echo` and `sudo` used together as shown below can have unexpected consequences. Please avoid such usage as far as possible.

I'm on Lubuntu 12.10 fully updated.

I know that what I'm asking could be a security risk but I would still like to understand what's happening.

I can get the following aliases to work:

```
fast='echo "mypassword" | sudo -S apt-fast update && sudo apt-fast upgrade'
nm='echo "mypassword" | sudo -S service network-manager restart'
aalog='echo "mypassword" | sudo -S aa-logprof'
reloadsm='echo "mypassword" | sudo -S apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/usr.local.seamonkey.seamonkey'
reloadgc='echo "mypassword" | sudo -S apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/opt.google.chrome.google-chrome'
```

But when I try this alias

```
pua='echo "mypassword" | sudo -S nano /etc/privoxy/user.action'
```

I see this:

```
[12:32 PM] ~ $ pua
Received SIGHUP or SIGTERMa: 
[12:32 PM] ~ $
```

Can someone please explain why this happens and if there's a way to fix the error-giving alias?

(I don't want to do anything involving sudoers.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a problem with nano, not the alias. Try using vim.

Comment: Could you please provide a link for that?

Comment: Why, did it work? :P

Comment: I can't find any resources but it seems the OS is killing the process off after you start it up or nano is running out of memory.